# calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder is empty first time, works subsequently

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ekeventstore

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here. My app is supposed to access the iPhone's various calendars to check on upcoming events. So I need access to "events" in the calendar and also "reminders". When I have the events I store them temporarily in UserDefaults

In my .h file I have stuff like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *calendars;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *reminders;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL accessToCalendarsGranted;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL accessToRemindersGranted;
```

and I need to get permission from the user to access these so in the main code I have code like this:

```
    -(void)requestCalendarAccess
{
    // Prompt the user for access to their Calendar

    [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (!granted)
        {
            NSLog(@"user has not granted access to calendars!!");
            // Display a message if the user has denied or restricted access to Calendar
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Privacy Warning", nil)
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Permission was not granted for Calendar", nil)
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", nil)
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

            return;
        }

        // Let's ensure that our code will be executed from the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // The user has granted access to their Calendar
            [self accessGrantedForCalendar];
        });
    }];
}
```

which is finished off by the code in accessGrantedForCalendar

```
_calendars = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCalendarListKey];

//if we have calendars stored in user defaults, we go and read them
if(!_calendars)
{
    _calendars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *phoneCalendarArray = [_eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

for (EKCalendar *systemCalendar in phoneCalendarArray)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *calendarDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[systemCalendar title], kCalendarName, [systemCalendar calendarIdentifier], kCalendarIndentifier, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCalendarWatched,  nil];

    [_calendars addObject:calendarDict];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_calendars forKey:kCalendarListKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

And this all works fairly well now. Lots of other code for actually getting events not included here.
The problem comes when I try the same approach for reminders:

```
-(void)requestRemindersAccess
{
    [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted)
        {
            // Let's ensure that our code will be executed from the main queue
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // The user has granted access to their Calendar
                [self accessGrantedForReminder];
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"user has not granted access to reminders!!");
            // Display a message if the user has denied or restricted access to Calendar
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Privacy Warning", nil)
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Permission was not granted for Reminders", nil)
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", nil)
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

and the code which finishes this in accessGrantedForReminder:

```
_reminders = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRemindersListKey];

//if we don't have reminders stored in user defaults, we go and read them
if(!_reminders || _reminders.count == 0)
{
    _reminders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //FOLLOWING LINE HAS PROBLEM FIRST TIME!!!
    NSArray *phoneReminderArray = [_eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];

for (EKCalendar *systemCalendar in phoneReminderArray)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *calendarDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[systemCalendar title], kCalendarName, [systemCalendar calendarIdentifier], kCalendarIndentifier, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCalendarWatched,  nil];

    [_reminders addObject:calendarDict];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_reminders forKey:kRemindersListKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

The line indicated above has a problem - the first time I run the application (i.e. immediately after receiving permission) I see phoneReminderArray has zero objects in it. If I exit the program and run again phoneReminderArray will get one object. It's driving me nuts - why does it only work after I exit the app (while the other calendars Home, Work & Birthdays) all seem to come up right away?

Any ideas anyone?

FYI I looked at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976831/ios-ekeventstore-sources-defaultcalendarfornewevents-calendarsforentitytype?rq=1) and it helped me figure out my initial problems with the first lot of calendar events, but it's not helping for Reminders

Comment: I'm having the same issue with only ekevents. The only thing I can think of is if you are trying to execute `accessGrantedForCalendar` _before_ `requestRemindersAccess` since they belong to the same `eventStore`. I've been struggling with this fora couple days now. I get the same things. Empty calendar array the first time, and a populated calendarArray after that.

Comment: I thought that might be the case too, but I put a breakpoint there and it's not hit before permission is granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple. 
Right before your call to the following line for fetching reminders:

```
  NSArray *phoneReminderArray = [_eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];
```

Place this line:

```
[_eventStore reset];
```

this should fix your problem.

Comment: I had the same "fun" with this, so why is this necessary? is it documented?

Comment: But it didn't do anything for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it to work after talashar's answer, I also tried the similar `refreshSourcesIfNecessary` method to no avail.

What did work for me: I had to call this line before asking for the list of reminder calendars:

```
[_eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];
```

After that, I was able to get the list of reminder calendars with:

```
[_eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder]
```